# Does the recovery model affect growth of the .mdf file?

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, recovery, recovery-model

On my production database, the `.mdf` file is rapidly growing on a daily basis.

If I change the recovery model from `SIMPLE` to `FULL`, will that help?

Comment: The recovery model will only affect how your transaction log grows. Not your mdf or ndf. Can you clarify what file is experiencing the growth?

Comment: Start with some reading from here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the simple recovery model only affects the log files of your database (.ldf).

If your datafiles are growing, you can check the tables that are occupying more space, **you can use the management studio: right click on the database> reports > standard reports > disk usage by top tables**

this way you can determine which table is taking all the space and plan a cleanup task for that (or move data to another DB)

Answer (score 0):

how does your transaction logs grows .could you provide more info like

1. what is your current recovery model ?

2.how often you take full backup and log backup ?

3.do you have auto growth settings ?

If  the problem is T-LOG growth,start 
with http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/73776/

Comment: OP indicates that it's a problem with their MDF file, which more than likely (although not guaranteed) to be their data file.